Is this a normal router log?
I looked at my router's log recently, and I discovered some unusual behavior. Is it normal, or is it some kind of virus / attack? Here are examples of some of the lines (MAC addresses replaced with letter X):
First set:
Oct 22 18:23:54 kernel: wl0: chanspec: 0x1009 (9)
Oct 22 18:23:55 acsd: eth5: selected_chspec is 0x1009 (9)
Oct 22 18:23:55 acsd: eth5: Adjusted channel spec: 0x1009 (9)
Oct 22 18:23:55 acsd: eth5: selected channel spec: 0x1009 (9)
Oct 22 18:23:55 acsd: eth5: txop channel select: Performing CSA on chspec 0x1009
Oct 22 18:40:24 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-84
Oct 22 18:40:24 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-84
Oct 22 18:40:25 kernel: wl1: random key value: [Letters and numbers]
Oct 22 18:40:25 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0

Second set:
Oct 24 19:34:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-48
Oct 24 19:34:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Previous authentication no longer valid (2), rssi:-48
Oct 24 19:34:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Station requesting (re)association is not authenticated with responding station (9), rssi:0
Oct 24 19:34:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 24 19:34:40 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 24 19:34:40 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-49

3rd set:
Oct 26 23:35:10 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-63
Oct 26 23:35:11 kernel: wl1: random key value: [Letters and numbers]
Oct 26 23:35:11 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 26 23:35:26 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(695): wl1.1: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-76
Oct 26 23:43:31 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-45
Oct 26 23:46:25 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 104 and rssi is -58
Oct 26 23:46:35 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 100 and rssi is -60
Oct 26 23:46:45 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 98 and rssi is -61
Oct 26 23:46:55 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 104 and rssi is -58
Oct 26 23:50:55 kernel: wl1: random key value: [Numbers and letters]
Oct 26 23:50:55 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:0
Oct 26 23:56:53 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 26 23:56:53 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-73

4th set:
Oct 19 01:04:16 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:0
Oct 19 01:09:18 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 19 01:09:18 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-69
Oct 19 01:09:50 kernel: wl1: random key value: [Letters and numbers]
Oct 19 01:09:50 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:0
Oct 19 01:12:02 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 19 01:12:02 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-68
Oct 19 01:41:08 dnsmasq[2857]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: [website]
Oct 19 01:41:08 dnsmasq[2857]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: [website]
Oct 19 01:41:08 dnsmasq[2857]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: [website]
Oct 19 01:41:08 dnsmasq[2857]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: [website]

5th set:
Oct 15 07:56:30 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl0.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-52
Oct 15 08:19:19 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-70
Oct 15 08:19:19 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-70
Oct 15 08:19:20 kernel: wl1: random key value: [Letters and numbers]
Oct 15 08:19:20 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 15 08:23:23 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-65
Oct 15 08:23:30 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-64
Oct 15 08:23:30 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-64
Oct 15 08:23:30 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-64
Oct 15 08:23:31 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 15 08:26:19 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-61
Oct 15 08:42:06 kernel: wl0: random key value: [Letters and numbers]
Oct 15 08:42:06 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl0.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 15 08:42:06 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl0.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0

6th set:
Oct 8 12:58:47 dnsmasq[2085]: Maximum number of concurrent DNS queries reached (max: 150)
Oct 8 12:59:15 kernel: bcm_i2c: bus 0: Failed to detect SFP: 100 retries exhausted

7th set:
Oct 12 21:12:52 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 92 and rssi is -64
Oct 12 21:14:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-65
Oct 12 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Station requesting (re)association is not authenticated with responding station (9), rssi:0
Oct 12 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 12 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 12 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-66
Oct 12 21:15:31 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 80 and rssi is -70
Oct 12 21:15:41 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 78 and rssi is -71

8th set:
Oct 4 22:54:19 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-63
Oct 4 23:00:04 disk_monitor: Got SIGALRM...
Oct 4 23:00:36 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 94 and rssi is -63
Oct 4 23:00:46 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 104 and rssi is -58

9th set:
Oct 2 15:13:54 kernel:  *** ERROR: [send_redir_page:625] # redir_url=https://[router URL]/blocking.asp?cat_id=75&mac=XXXXXXXXXXXX&domain=[suspicious website]

10th set:
Sep 29 01:05:04 kernel: wlc_mbss_validate_mac: wl1.1 ignore mac validation
Sep 29 01:05:04 acsd: eth5: Selecting 2g band ACS policy
Sep 29 01:05:04 kernel: wlc_mbss_validate_mac: wl0.1 ignore mac validation
Sep 29 01:05:05 acsd: acsd_main_loop(1125): sync_id: 22615, status:1, misc.error/abort
Sep 29 01:05:05 wlceventd: main(1239): wlceventd Start...
Sep 29 01:05:05 acsd: acs_candidate_score_busy(951): eth5: busy check failed for chanspec: 0x1903 (5u)
Sep 29 01:05:05 acsd: acs_candidate_score_intf(1003): eth5: intf check failed for chanspec: 0x1903 (5u)

11th set:
Oct 25 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Station requesting (re)association is not authenticated with responding station (9), rssi:0
Oct 25 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 25 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 25 21:14:42 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-66
Oct 25 21:15:31 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 80 and rssi is -70
Oct 25 21:15:41 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 78 and rssi is -71
Oct 25 21:15:46 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 102 and rssi is -59
Oct 25 21:17:21 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 86 and rssi is -67
Oct 25 21:17:26 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 94 and rssi is -63
Oct 25 21:26:18 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-66
Oct 25 21:26:18 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl1.1: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-66
Oct 25 21:26:19 kernel: wl1: random key value: [Numbers and letters]
Oct 25 21:26:19 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(662): wl1.1: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Oct 25 21:30:20 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(685): wl1.1: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Oct 25 21:30:20 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(722): wl1.1: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-66
Oct 25 21:37:02 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 86 and rssi is -67
Oct 25 21:37:07 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 86 and rssi is -67

12th set:
Sep 24 12:11:00 kernel: br0: received packet on eth5.0 with own address as source address
Sep 24 12:11:00 kernel: br0: received packet on eth5.0 with own address as source address
Sep 24 12:11:00 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(540): eth5: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-66
Sep 24 12:11:00 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth5 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 24 12:11:00 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: ifname=eth5, event=143, token=ab, status=1, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00
Sep 24 12:11:00 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: not for interface eth7
Sep 24 12:11:00 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth5 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 24 12:11:00 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: ifname=eth5, event=143, token=7d, status=7, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00
Sep 24 12:11:00 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: not for interface eth7
Sep 24 12:11:05 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-86
Sep 24 12:11:05 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-86
Sep 24 12:11:05 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-86
Sep 24 12:11:06 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth7: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 24 12:11:28 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-70
Sep 24 12:11:28 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-70
Sep 24 12:11:29 kernel: wl0: random key value: [Numbers and letters]
Sep 24 12:11:29 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 24 12:12:41 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 84 and rssi is -68
Sep 24 12:12:57 roamast: sta[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX] on ap[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX], rcpi is 76 and rssi is -72
Sep 24 12:13:04 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(530): eth6: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Sep 24 12:13:04 kernel: br0: received packet on eth6.0 with own address as source address
Sep 24 12:13:04 kernel: br0: received packet on eth6.0 with own address as source address
Sep 24 12:13:04 kernel: wl0: random key value: [Numbers and letters]
Sep 24 12:13:04 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(540): eth6: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-81
Sep 24 12:13:04 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 24 12:13:04 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 24 12:13:12 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(530): eth7: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Sep 24 12:13:12 kernel: br0: received packet on eth7.0 with own address as source address
Sep 24 12:13:12 kernel: br0: received packet on eth7.0 with own address as source address

13th set:
Sep 23 21:26:00 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth6: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:26:00 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(540): eth7: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-74
Sep 23 21:26:31 acsd: acs_set_chspec: 0x1007 (7) for reason APCS_CSTIMER
Sep 23 21:26:31 kernel: wl0: chanspec: 0x1007 (7)
Sep 23 21:26:42 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth7 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:26:43 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: ifname=eth5, event=143, token=b6, status=0, mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:26:43 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: STA accept
Sep 23 21:26:43 kernel: br0: received packet on eth7.0 with own address as source address
Sep 23 21:26:43 kernel: br0: received packet on eth7.0 with own address as source address
Sep 23 21:26:43 kernel: wl0: random key value: [Numbers and letters]
Sep 23 21:26:43 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:26:43 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:26:43 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(540): eth7: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-60
Sep 23 21:26:44 acsd: eth5: selected_chspec is 0x1007 (7)
Sep 23 21:26:44 acsd: eth5: Adjusted channel spec: 0x1007 (7)
Sep 23 21:26:44 acsd: eth5: selected channel spec: 0x1007 (7)
Sep 23 21:26:44 acsd: eth5: txop channel select: Performing CSA on chspec 0x1007
Sep 23 21:31:24 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth5 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:31:25 bsd: bsd: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX no response
Sep 23 21:31:25 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth5 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:31:26 bsd: bsd: STA:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX no response
Sep 23 21:31:26 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-86
Sep 23 21:31:27 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Previous authentication no longer valid (2), rssi:-86
Sep 23 21:31:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(530): eth5: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:31:39 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(559): eth5: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-80
Sep 23 21:31:43 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-80
Sep 23 21:31:43 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-80
Sep 23 21:31:44 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-78
Sep 23 21:31:47 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:32:21 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Unspecified reason (1), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:32:21 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(530): eth5: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:32:21 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Unspecified reason (1), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:32:21 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(530): eth5: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:32:21 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(559): eth5: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-73
Sep 23 21:35:47 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth7 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:35:48 bsd: bsd: STA:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX no response
Sep 23 21:35:48 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth7 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:35:48 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: ifname=eth5, event=143, token=b9, status=0, mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:35:48 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: not for token ba
Sep 23 21:35:48 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-59
Sep 23 21:35:48 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3), rssi:-59
Sep 23 21:35:49 kernel: br0: received packet on eth7.0 with own address as source address
Sep 23 21:35:49 kernel: br0: received packet on eth7.0 with own address as source address
Sep 23 21:35:49 kernel: wl0: random key value: [numbers and letters]
Sep 23 21:35:49 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(540): eth7: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:-72
Sep 23 21:35:49 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:35:49 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:39:04 bsd: bsd: Sending act Frame to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with transition target eth5 ssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:39:04 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: ifname=eth7, event=143, token=bb, status=6, mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Sep 23 21:39:04 bsd: bsd: BSS Transit Response: STA reject
Sep 23 21:39:04 bsd: bsd: Skip STA:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX reject BSSID
Sep 23 21:42:20 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(530): eth5: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: Successful (0), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:42:20 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(494): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, status: 0, reason: Unspecified reason (1), rssi:0
Sep 23 21:42:20 kernel: br0: received packet on eth5.0 with own address as source address
Sep 23 21:42:20 kernel: br0: received packet on eth5.0 with own address as source address

Are these logs are normal, or are they abnormal (is the router compromised?) Could it be an attack?
For example, is receiving a packet with "own address as source address" normal? Is "Sending act Frame to [MAC address]" with "transition target" to [different MAC address] normal?
Is it considered normal for devices to constantly authenticate and de-authenticate, and for those devices to constantly associate, disassociate, and re-associate?
Is it considered normal for a device to be de-authenticated due to an "unspecified reason"? Is "Possible DNS-rebind attack detected" (from some website I've never heard of) normal?
In one of the logs, check_node_data found "wrong data CRC in data node", in which it read a certain letter/number string, but calculated a different letter/number string. It said "Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint", and "loading out-of-tree module taints kernel".
There has also been "Deep green mode" running and I don't know what that is.
If the router is compromised / infected, do I have to get a new router? I already reset the router to its default settings (and installed the newest firmware), and nothing has changed. If there is a problem, can it be fixed, or would it require buying a new router?
Is there a computer program which can scan a log file (from a router) using AI to detect abnormalities in the log? And is there a computer program which can actively monitor the network of a router (and scan for potential intruders / attacks)?

A) I think it was a little unnecessary to include that many repeating ‘sets’, and B) this behaviour is mostly benign, even normal. This isn’t an attack; at worse maybe a faulty signal or such.

Your router isn’t being attacked. There are many applications that can parse and filter log files. Software recommendations are out of scope. AI is useless in a case like this, if you were to upload the text, to say ChatGPT it will acknowledge whatever query you ask it. Waste of time.
